# Changing an appended clone object in a loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working JavaScript gist that create randomly three squares on the screen.
The problem is now it's creating via the toAppend and clone() (see Initial Code at the bottom) 3 times the very same html block.

It generates currently:

```
<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-target="#myInfoModal" data-toggle="modal" ></span></div>
<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-target="#myInfoModal" data-toggle="modal" ></span></div>
<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-target="#myInfoModal" data-toggle="modal" ></span></div>
```

**I would like to have TO generate for each a different data-target for each div**, like that:

```
<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-target="#myInfoModal1"  data-toggle="modal" ></span></div>
<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-target="#myInfoModal2"  data-toggle="modal" ></span></div>
<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-target="#myInfoModal3"  data-toggle="modal" ></span></div>
```

The number 3 would come from the "var numInfoSquares"

**INITIAL CODE**

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () { 

    // Use jquery to display X squares according 
    var numInfoSquares = 3;
    var $zone = $("#zone");
    var $toAppend = $('<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myInfoModal"></span></div>');
    for (var c = 0; c < numInfoSquares; c++)
      $zone.append($toAppend.clone());
    // place squares randomly on the page
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
    }
    $(".info-square").each(function () {
      var topPosition = getRandomInt(8, 70);  
      var leftPosition = getRandomInt(8, 92); 
      $(this).css({
        "top": topPosition+"%",
        "left": leftPosition+"%",
      });
    });   
  });
```

**EDIT thanks to TJ Crowder**

I tried to apply two solutions:

1/ First suggested solution

Worked perfectly

2/ Second suggested solution (use a temporary variable) : did not work

```
 $(document).on('ready page:load', function () { 

    // Use jquery to display X squares according 
    var numInfoSquares = 3;
    var $zone = $("#zone");
    var $toAppend = $('<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-toggle="modal"></span></div>');

    for (var c = 0; c < numInfoSquares; c++)
      var $clone = $toAppend.clone();
      $clone.find('.square').attr("data-target", "#myInfoModal" + (c + 1));
      $zone.append($clone);

    // place squares randomly on the page
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
    }
    $(".info-square").each(function () {
      var topPosition = getRandomInt(8, 70);  
      var leftPosition = getRandomInt(8, 92); 
      $(this).css({
        "top": topPosition+"%",
        "left": leftPosition+"%",
      });
    });   
  });
```

But it has 2 problems:

- **it only now generate 1 square** (instead of three)
- and it does not create data-target="#myInfoModal1", "#myInfoModal2"  and data-target="#myInfoModal3" but instead generate a data-target="#myInfoModal4" although I wanted 3 of them (not the number 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `data-target` from this line:

```
var $toAppend = $('<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-toggle="modal"></span></div>');
```

and then in your loop, assign it to the clone's span, including your loop index `c` (plus one, since you wanted 1, 2, 3 but `c` will be 0, 1, 2):

```
$zone.append(
    $toAppend.clone()
        .find('.square').attr("data-target", "#myInfoModal" + (c + 1))
        .end()
);
```

There, we

1. Clone it
2. [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the span
3. Add the attribute
4. [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to get back the jQuery object for the overall clone
5. ...and append that

Alternately, we could use a temporary variable:

```
var $clone = $toAppend.clone();
$clone.find('.square').attr("data-target", "#myInfoModal" + (c + 1));
$zone.append($clone);
```

Comment: thanks! it almost work .You're the first one to manage to increment the #myinfoModal. the only problem preventing it to work is that with your solution dat-target is appended to the div and not inside the span. I need it inside the span. Her's what your code produce: <div style="top: 13%; left: 75%;" data-target="#myInfoModal2" class="info-square"><span class="square" data-toggle="modal"></span></div>

Comment: @Mathieu: Ah, yes, we wanted a `find` and an `end` -- added.

Comment: edited my question, your first solution worked like a charm, not the second one so I documented the results so that future selfs :) will be able to leverage on that. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Mathieu: Glad that helped. Re the question edit: You need to use `{}` with the `for` loop. Only the first of the three lines is in the loop. (Hint: This is why it's best to **always** use `{}`, even when you only have one statement inside.)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>My title</title>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
          var numInfoSquares = 3;
          var $zone = $("#zone");
          for (var c = 0; c < numInfoSquares; c++)
            $zone.append('<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myInfoModal' + (c + 1) + '"></span></div>');
          function getRandomInt(min, max) {
              return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
          }
          $(".info-square").each(function () {
              var topPosition = getRandomInt(8, 70);
              var leftPosition = getRandomInt(8, 92);
              $(this).css({
                  "top": topPosition + "%",
                  "left": leftPosition + "%",
              });
          });
      });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="zone"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does not work. if I check chrome dev tools it says <div style="top: 13.%; left: 55%; display: block;" class="info-square"><span class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myInfoModalNaN"></span></div>